# Creat new repository from local to bitbucket without using another CVS app

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have just created a bitbucket account after creating a project with Visual Studio. It is not open source, so I want to keep the sources private.

After reading bitbucket's documentation, the only option I can see to upload sources from my local machine to my new created-from-scratch repository is to first create a Git repository, then import. But, if I have a free account on Github, anything committed will be publicly available.

Is there a workaround to upload sources to my new bitbucket repository bypassing the need to use a 3rd party CVS?

(P.S: Gotta say that I love Git and Github, but right now I cannot afford a private repository account).

Comment: You seem to be confusing git, github and bitbucket. They are not the same thing. Bitbucket allows you to use git.

Comment: Not really, @Burhan. Note that I'm saying Git AND Github in my question. In my knowledge is that Git is the repository and Github is just a hosting service for Git repositories. Bitbucket is another hosting service just like Github. Now, your comment made me think that I was wrong in one point: The fact that bitbucket needs you to previously have a Git repository for your code does not mean that it has to be stored in Github and being public (remember that all my story comes from the fact that I don't want to pay for my repository remote storage). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to a new folder and run

```
Git init
```

Then

```
Git remote add origin your-repo-name
```

Move your project into the folder ie copy the files.  Then do

```
Git status
```

If you've done this correctly you should see your new files in red

Comment: Thank you @Joe. Despite your answer being useful, I made a concept mistake as I explained to Burhan. I appreciate it.